# How to hook up two water well pressure tanks?

Tags: plumbing, water, well, water-tank

Our high-producing well & pump need two bladder pressure tanks. How should those be hooked up? I've come up with two possible configurations.

1. Do either of these work?
2. Is one considered the "right" way?
3. Do I need to move the pressure switch in either diagram?

[image]

Comment: @Ruskes I understand series vs parallel for electricity but am new to bladder tanks and find the single connection confusing. Would it be correct to think of diagram 2 as "half of the parallel setup" when water is filling tanks and the "other half" when water is flowing out?

Comment: @Ruskes Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

In a hydraulic system (water or otherwise), the pressure at any give point is the same as any other location, barring high volume leaks or similar flow circumstances. With that foundation, placement of the tank is going to be a matter of convenience and physical plant. My well housing has a pressure tank in the pump "house" which has a roof that is a back-breaker to lift. When I last replaced the tank, I added a second tank at the pump output approximately eighty feet away, which is a series installation. As long as the bladder pressures are the same, the system will function as a single tank. In my case, the doubled volume has resulted in less-frequent pump operation.

Comment: I though water pressure decreased with the length of run which is why we have to  put in bigger pipes to our irrigation. So are you saying in this instance it is negligible. I'm guessing it doesn't matter if one tank fills slightly ahead of the other because as it gets close to full the increasing resistance allows the other tank to catch up. In other words the system is always moving toward equilibrating pressure at all points. So, as you said, I can just think of the pressure being equal everywhere. Am I close to understanding?

Comment: I think you are "close to understanding." Water pressure decreasing with the length of the run is not a factor for a nearly-static environment such as pump cut-off.

Answer (score 1):

For proper operation the pressure switch should be quite close to **a** pressure tank. Anything which needlessly increases the distance from the switch to **a** pressure tank is not good and may result in problems.

*Other* pressure tanks can be wherever it's convenient. Or you can move the pressure switch if that's more convenient, so long as it ends up quite close to a pressure tank.

Thus, Diagram 2 is bad. Diagram 1 is fine. A different version of Diagram 2 with the pressure switch relocated near one of the tanks could be fine, but the additional plumbing complexity adds no benefit.

Comment: Is the difference between 14" and 27" distance between tank and switch significant?